# How can Maven handle two versions of the same dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I've built an API with Spring, which should implement multiple, external `.jar` files as dependencies. Right now, I am loading all these `.jar` files via reflection, which comes with high performance losses. Therefore I want to add them as dependency in the `POM.xml` file.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The problem is, that I need to have two versions of each dependency, which can both be accessed by the application.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does anybody knows how I could manage multiple versions of the same dependency in Maven or knows how to work around it?

I highly appreciate any kind of help or suggestion, cheers!

Comment: This goes deeply against how maven works and any workaround will be painful. Consider rethinking your architecture

Comment: Also, there is no official way of doing this with maven. All answers you'd find about this will be workarounds to achieve this goal and could be very painfull

Comment: The could not **official way** because that would mean the JVM (runtime) need to have a way to handle duplicate classes. The only rule it has is the first one on the classpath will be picked up.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I already considered that, but I have no idea at all... :D